# Alternative syntax for Vue on IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I have a for loop in vue

```
 <div class="inputWrap" v-for="(thing,index) in things">
```

And I want to use the index as part of an id

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="another_thing" :id="`another_thing_${index}`">
```

Which works okay, but not in IE11. What would be an alternative syntax that would be accepted by IE11?

Current error

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:invalid expression: Invalid character in ...
```

Comment: try using `id="another_thing_{{index}}">` instead

Comment: Accompanying @Eldar 's comment, the problem is the template string which is not supported by Internet Explorer: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: This also produces a similar error - Error compiling template: Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">. So does :id=another_thing_{{index}}

Comment: Use a method that accepts an index and returns the ID, and v-bind it to the id attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically I would recommend doing string concatenations and manipulations in the JS logic itself instead of within the template, so that it is easier to reason about. Your problem can be solved if you bind a method to the `id` attribute:

```
<div class="inputWrap" v-for="(thing,index) in things">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="another_thing" :id="getCheckboxId(index)">
</div>
```

You can then create a new method in your VueJS component that returns the appropriate ID:

```
methods: {
  getCheckboxId: function(index) {
    return 'another_thing_' + index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Template Literals are not supported in IE 11. You can just concatenate the string using `+` or you can try using the [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) method instead to append the index number of your loop to your id like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="another_thing" :id="another_thing_" + index)> // using +
<input type="checkbox" v-model="another_thing" :id="another_thing_".concat(index)> // using concat()
```

Comment: Let me know if this works or not so I can remove it if it doesn't. Can't really check the above approach and verify if it works in your Vue environment or not as I have not used Vue before.